# Rails - Why render :js is not working in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Render :js is not working in production, any idea ?

Even with `remote: true` and `format: :js` in the `form_with`, the controller processed the request as HTML and send the js code only as plain text

In production log

```
I, [2021-02-28T13:51:50.415176 #462958]  INFO -- : [0821e821-d677-41fd-9698-6e10c2ec40cf] Processing by CommentController#create as HTML
I, [2021-02-28T13:51:50.415309 #462958]  INFO -- : [0821e821-d677-41fd-9698-6e10c2ec40cf]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "message"=>"hello"}
```

The controller process the request as HTML while it's as JS in local with the same code

controller.rb

```
def create

if @comment.save
     render :js => "confirm('comment sent')"
else
    render :js => "alert('comment not sent')"
end

end
```

Local log

```
Started POST "/comment" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-02-28 13:38:03 +0100
Processing by CommentController#create as JS
```

The view

```
    <%= form_with :url => { :controller => 'comment', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>   
          <%= f.label :message %>:
          <%= f.text_area :message, size: '250x200' %> 
          <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
    <% end %>
```

Edit :

Even processed as JS the problem remain

I also use Phusion Passenger with Nginx

Comment: I suppose it works on local right? Could you add some logs?

Comment: @LinkOfCode can you add more details to your question.

Comment: @razvans yes it's working

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you add the format at the end of the action, like /create.js? Please add the code which makes the post.

Comment: I wouldn't do the form like that though. Use Comment.new instead of the plain url. Rails will know to 'create' that comment. Use remote: true to make it :js

Comment: @razvans add .js work for to make process the controller 'as JS'  instead 'as HTML' but the js code is always return in plain text and not executed ?? :/

Comment: Remove render js and add a template "create.js". Write a alert('works') there see if it works

Comment: @razvans same result, I even try to add `data: {type: 'script'}` or `render layout: false`